# Splitting a line from a text file into seperate variables in C

Tags: c

I am currently working on a program that reads in a file named accidents.txt, which contains data for fatal traffic accidents, and organizes the data into three different structs based on the time of the accident.

**Text file format:**

time(24 hour format)    numOfVehicles   numOfFatalities

**A few lines from the txt file:**

```
2   2   1
18  3   1
1   1   1
7   2   1
19  1   1
```

It is important to note that they are separated by tabs(/t).

I have the entire program written and it should work, besides reading in the actual file and separating the lines to store into my structs. The entire goal of the program is to add up the total amount of accidents, vehicles, and fatalities involved in each time frame and outputting it.

Something within the while statement, specifically the start of the while statement is incorrect. After a few hours of trying to figure out what I am doing wrong, I cannot seem to figure it out. Below is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Structure for organizing file data
struct stats {
    int accidents, vehicles, fatalities;
    double vehAccRat;
};

int main(void) {
    // Declare file pointer
    FILE *fp;

    char line[256];

    // Declare file name
    char* filename = "accidents.txt";

    // Declare structure variables
    struct stats morning;
    struct stats afternoon;
    struct stats night;

    // Open a file using fopen function then assign it to the file pointer
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    // If file is not found, exit program
    if (!fp){
        printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
        exit(1);
    } // End of if statement

    // Iterate through file by each line and store data into respective time frame
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line),fp) != NULL) {
        // Store line data in array
        char *val1 = strtok(NULL, "/t");
        char *val2 = strtok(NULL, "/t");
        char *val3 = strtok(NULL, "/t");

        // If time is from 6 - 12 add data to morning statistics
        if (val1 <= 6 && val1 >= 12) {
            morning.accidents += 1;
            morning.vehicles += val2;
            morning.fatalities += val3;
        } // End of if statement

        // If time is from 13 - 19 add data to afternoon statistics
        else if (val1 <= 13 && val1 >= 19) {
            afternoon.accidents += 1;
            afternoon.vehicles += val2;
            afternoon.fatalities += val3;
        } // End of else if statement

        // If time is from 20 - 23 or 0 - 5 add data to night statistics
        else if ((val1 <= 20 && val1 >= 23) || (val1 <= 0 && val1 >= 5)) {
            night.accidents += 1;
            night.vehicles += val2;
            night.fatalities += val3;
        } // End of else if statement
    } // End of while loop

    // Close the file stream
    fclose(fp);

    // Calculate vehicle / accident ratio for each time group
    morning.vehAccRat = morning.vehicles / morning.accidents;
    afternoon.vehAccRat = afternoon.vehicles / afternoon.accidents;
    night.vehAccRat = night.vehicles / night.accidents;

    // Output data organized by time of day (morning/afternoon/night)
    printf("Time Span\tAccidents\tVehicles\tFatals\t\tVeh./Acc.\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Morning\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%.4f\n", morning.accidents, morning.vehicles, morning.fatalities, morning.vehAccRat);
    printf("Afternoon\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%.4f\n", afternoon.accidents, afternoon.vehicles, afternoon.fatalities, afternoon.vehAccRat);
    printf("Night\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%.4f\n", night.accidents, night.vehicles, night.fatalities, night.vehAccRat);
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");

} // End of int main(void)
```

Thanks in advance for any help, I am completely stumped.

Comment: The first time you use `strtok` on a string, you need to tell it which string you actually want to tokenize. You can only pass it `NULL` when it is already tokenizing a string.

Comment: You can use `fgets` to read the line, followed by `int itemsRead = sscanf(line, "%d%d%d", &timeOfCrash, &numOfVehicles, &numOfFatalities);` which will eat up all the whitespace. You can use `strtok` but it is overkill. Your code `if (val1 <= 6 && val1 >= 12)` is treating the pointers as if `strtok` converted the sub-strings to integers, but it didn't, `val1` was and still is a `char*` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I noticed is the first call to strtok should have the string to tokenise, then subsequent ones having NULL, but all yours have NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I think `sscanf` of `fscanf` would be your friends here.

The loop could be replaced with the following to read each of the three values per line into integers:

```
 int val1, val2, val3;
 while(fscanf(fp, "%d%d%d", &val1, &val2, &val3) == 3){
```

You could also use `sscanf` on `line` in your current implementation, but that feels unnecessary.